# Weblogic 12cR2 Nodemanager native library not work on mac os x

Tags: java, macos, weblogic, native

[image]http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/NODEM/java_nodemgr.htm#NODEM178

Oracle official document Stated (weblogic 12cR2 on Mac os x):

```
NativeVersionEnabled

A value of true causes native libraries for the operating system to be used.

For UNIX systems other than Solaris or Linux, set this property to false to run Node Manager in non-native mode. This will cause Node Manager to use the start script specified by the weblogic.StartScriptEnabled property to start Managed Servers.

Note that when NativeVersionEnabled=false:

Node Manager cannot query if a PID is alive nor kill a particular process

Node Manager does not have the ability to determine if there are existing processes that need to be monitored and crash recovery is not fully implemented

nmKill is not supported when NativeVersionEnabled=false and weblogic.StartScriptEnabled=true
```

If I set this value to false, node manager can be started and work, but it will cause seriously problem when run weblogic 12cR2 on Mac os x as NodeManager not manage the managed server properly.

Any work around available?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides native Node Manager libraries for Windows, Solaris, Linux on Intel, Linux on Z-Series, and AIX operating systems.

Only workaround is not to use NativeVersion and make sure that weblogic.StartScriptEnabled set to true so that it will use script to start servers.

Comment: Yeah, when "NativeVersion" was disabled, and "StartScriptEnabled" as enabled, node manger can be started, but not make any sense as it not query any managed server status. Not useful at all.